# Embed python2.7 in a C program, using CMakeLists.txt. Static libraries linking

Tags: python, c, gcc, cmake, static-linking

I'm doing some trials to embed python in a c program.

I use CMake 2.8.12.2 and gcc 4.8.1 to build the application. My Python version is 2.7.11. Running on W7.

This is how I'm linking the libraries in the CMakeLists.txt, which has always worked for me before with static libraries:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.7 FATAL_ERROR)

project(testpy)

include_directories("C:\\Anaconda\\include")
link_directories("C:\\Anaconda\\libs")

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(SOURCE_FILES testpy.c)

add_executable(testpy ${SOURCE_FILES} Python.h)

set(PYLIB_DIR  "C:\\Anaconda\\libs")
message(${PYLIB_DIR})
find_library(PYlib python27.lib HINTS ${PYLIB_DIR})
include_directories(${PYLIB_DIR})
message(${PYlib})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testpy ${PYlib})
```

testpy.c

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\nprint('Today is',ctime(time())\n)");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I am getting when making:

```
CMakeFiles\testpy.dir/objects.a(testpy.c.obj):testpy.c:(.text.startup+0x10): und
efined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
CMakeFiles\testpy.dir/objects.a(testpy.c.obj):testpy.c:(.text.startup+0x25): und
efined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles
\testpy.dir/objects.a(testpy.c.obj): bad reloc address 0x25 in section `.text.st
artup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link
 failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\testpy.dir\build.make:90: recipe for target 'testpy.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [testpy.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/testpy.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testpy.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm pretty shure is a linking problem, but I still not seing where it is, and how to fix it. Seen and tried also a lot of solutions suggested here and in other forums without success.

In both \include and \libs folders can be found the python.h and the python27.lib, respectively.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.